# bootstrapValidator.js com jsf não funciona

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsf, dom

Meu script de validação usando bootstrapValidator.js

```
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" target="head" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" target="head" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#formAgendaMedica').bootstrapValidator({
                live : 'disabled',
                fields : {
                    'formAgendaMedica:paciente_input' : {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Informe o paciente'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'formAgendaMedica:progama_input' : {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Informe o programa'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'formAgendaMedica:grupo_input' : {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Informe o grupo'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    'formAgendaMedica:atendimento_input' : {
                        validators : {
                            notEmpty : {
                                message : 'Informe o atendimento'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
```

O cenário é o seguinte, eu abro minha tela que tem o form que estou validando com script acima, porém você pode ver que estou validando 4 campos que não podem ser null.

Primeiro teste:

Assim que abro o form dou submit para ver se está funcionando, porém em meu DOM só está renderizado ainda paciente_input e progama_input, até aqui funcionado perfeitamente se tiver null ele executar corretamente o script.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém os outros dois campos são renderizado quando eu preencho o campo progama_input, feito isso quando vou testar se grupo e atendimento for null bloquear o submit o jsf faz um redirect para a mesma página e ainda volta com o seguinte erro no console.

Perceba na imagem abaixo que grupo agora está acessivel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando dou submit novamente para testar o null do input de grupo o jsf faz um redirect e retorna isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acredito que você não precisa do `$ = jQuery;`.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode usar Dessa forma

> $ = jQuery;

Substitua todos **$** por **JQuery**, isso gera conflitos com as lib primefaces, sei que o JQuery e Outros JS dizem que pode fazer o que fez.

Mas não fuciona!

Uso sempre **JQuery** ao inves de $, quando coloco libs .js nos meus projetos tenho sempre acertar dessa forma para que funcione.

Seu script loader parece também estar errado: 
usamos assim aqui

```
<!-- para usar JQuery nos scripts -->
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="primefaces.js" />
```

Outro detalhe **dentro da tag head** da view

Comment: eu já tentei isso, porém não funciona tbm..

Answer (score 1):

Outra forma de evitar conflitos ao utilizar jQuery é isolar o seu uso dentro de uma função IIF. Exemplo:

```
+function($){

//Insira todo seu código aqui    

}(jQuery);
```